# How to use C# Re-mix mixins with Protobuf

Tags: c#, protobuf-net, mixins, composition

I've been working on an entity/component based game engine, and I wanted to use Mixins for the components. However, these components need to be de/serializable. So, I've decided to use http://remix.codeplex.com/ and Protobuf Net.

However, I'm not sure how to serialize my Mix-in instances, since I have little experience with both frameworks. So,

- I'm looking for an example on how to do this,
- or wether or not a mix-in instance is already serializable/deserializable as is.

Thanks for you time.

Comment: I'm not familiar with remix; what problems are you encountering? how does it appear at runtime? do you end up with generated subclasses of the original types?

Comment: This is something I wanted to find out before trying to implement the remix library into my project. I'm going to try to get test project up and running by the end of the day. Hopefully, these 'mixin' instances just automatically get treated as a collection and protobuf serializes/deserializes them correctly. Though, that doesn't seem likely since they seem to be much more complex than a mere collection.

Comment: unfortunately, I don't know enough about how remix is implemented to answer this ;p If you can provide any input or examples, I suspect it can be made to work